# Active MQ - HelloWorld example exception

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic

I'm trying to run the hello world example [found here](http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html)

I added **activemq-all-5.5.1.jar** to the libraries already

It builds successfully with the following warning

> warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6

But it doesn't run, I get this exception

> **Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/jms/JMSException**
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>       at hw_testing.HW_testing$HelloWorldProducer.run(HW_testing.java:69)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> **Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/jms/JMSException**
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>       at hw_testing.HW_testing$HelloWorldProducer.run(HW_testing.java:69)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

...
And the same exception for thread 3 and 4

Can anybody help me with that please?

Answer (score 12):

This is a problem with dependencies (`javax/jms/JMSException` is in multiple jars), which occurs e.g. with `javaee-api` (5 or 6) - this jar lacks some method bodies for several classes. `activemq-all-5.5.1.jar` also contains `javax.jms.JMSException` but these classes are not identical. If `javaee-api` comes first in classpath, you will get the `java.lang.ClassFormatError`.

If you use maven, put `javaee-api` *after* `activemq-all` (or remove it). In general, remove unecessary dependencies.